# Which maths function will give me the correct rounding functionality?

Tags: c#, math, rounding

I have the following line of code:

```
var loan = (int)(Math.Truncate((usableIncome / avgRate) / loanMultiple) * loanMultiple);
```

At present,as you can see I'm using Math.Truncate to always take the integer part of the number. So if the equation throws up 5.1, 5.5 or 5.9, I always resolve back to 5.

I need to make a change so that I get to the nearest whole number. 5.1 would still be 5, and 5.5, 5.9 would resolve to 6. I'm not really concerned which way 5.5 goes.

Anybody advise which is the best function to use in these circumstances?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use Math.Round() function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking [`Math.Round(Double, MidpointRounding)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131274%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

> Rounds a decimal value to the nearest integer. A parameter specifies
>   how to round the value if it is midway between two numbers.

```
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(5.1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(5.5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(5.9, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
```

Output will be;

```
5
6
6
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/0TszEg)</kbd>.

Comment: Chosen this answer because it also demonstrates the rounding options available on this function.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the built-in Round function

```
  var loan = Math.Round(((usableIncome / avgRate) / loanMultiple) * loanMultiple),MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following approach :

```
double num = (((double)usableIncome / (double)avgRate) / (double)loanMultiple) * loanMultiple);
var loan = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(num, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
```

Answer (score 2):

Math.Round()  does exactly that. For example:

```
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(4.4)); // 4
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(4.5)); // 4
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(4.6)); // 5
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(5.5)); // 6
```

If you need more info you can read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
var loan = (int)(Math.Round((usableIncome / avgRate) / loanMultiple) * loanMultiple);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Math.Round?

```
Math.Round(5.4,0);
//Gives 5
Math.Round(5.5,0);
//Gives 6
Math.Round(5.6,0);
//Gives 6
```